# How do I change marker image react-native?

Tags: javascript, ios, dictionary, react-native

Just use `react-native`, how do I change the marker image in `mapview`? Can't seem to find any information on that. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunately not possible with current implementation of native MapView, as far as I've examined it.

I suggest you to use https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl instead. It offers much more options and functionality than MapView.